# How to pre-populate checkboxes based on URL parameters

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to pre-populate checkboxes based on URL parameters. I have no experience with javascript so I can't get other solutions to work for me.

Consider the following setup:

```
<form method='GET'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="1" id="1"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="2" id="2"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="3" id="3"/>
  <button type="submit">Apply</button>
</form>
```

I want the second checkbox and first checkbox to be ticked when `?a=2&a=1` is observed in the URL.

This is what I have tried but the code does not work.

```
<script>
var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');

for (i in sURLVariables) { 
  let sParameter =sURLVariables[i].split('='); 
  let name=sParameter[0];
  let value=decodeURIComponent(sParameter[1]);
  let id=decodeURIComponent(sParameter[1]);

  let collection = document.getElementById(id)
  for(j in collection){
    if(collection[j].id==id)collection[j].checked=true
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: 1. `if` comparison should have `==`. 2. Use `URLSearchParams`. 3. `value` and `id` should be inside quotes

Comment: Fixed points 1 & 3 but for point 2 do you mean something like

```URLSearchParams(window.location.search.substring(1))```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams. You don't have to manually split and check

Comment: in html code `id` and `value` will be in double quotes. and in javascript this do this

`document.getElementById(window.location.href.split("?a=")[1]).checked=true`

Comment: Mmm, it works for single parameter but fails for multiple ```?a=1&a=3``` Maybe I should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this kind of approach

```js
let fakeQueryString = "a=2&a=3"; //replace it with actual url
let searchParms = new URLSearchParams(fakeQueryString);

for(const [key,val] of searchParms)
  document.getElementById(val).checked = true;
```

```html
<form method='GET'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="1" id="1"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="2" id="2"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="3" id="3"/>
  <button type="submit">Apply</button>
</form>
```